# Where is the wiki formatted text converted to html?

Tags: php, templates, mediawiki

I need to find the main function in MediaWiki where wiki text is converted to html.  Does someone know where that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by a set of functions within the following file:

**includes/parser/Parser.php**

The list of functions, their actions and purposes are detailed within that file.

(Was easily found by searching through the MediaWiki source code for "*nowiki*" which is a distinct piece of the markup language.)